# Cannot read CD in DVD-RW drive

Tags: troubleshooting, dvd, compact-disc

My DVD-RW drive has stopped recognizing CDs, but it can read and write DVDs flawlessly.

Is this a software or a hardware problem? How can I fix thus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had much the same issue with my Lite-on DVD writer. Oddly enough it seemed to happen directly after a windowsXP update. After some research on the 'net (much like you are doing now) I found others with the same issue, remedied by flashing the firmware on my DVD drive. I found some good tips and the correct firmware at [The Firmware Page](http://forum.rpc1.org/portal.php)
If you can tell me/us the make/model of your DVD drive, then maybe some more specific help can find its way to you.